# Haskell typeclass

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have a Haskell typeclass question.  I can't munge the syntax to get this (seemingly reasonable) program to compile under GHC.

```
import Control.Concurrent.MVar

blah1 :: [a] -> IO ([a])
blah1 = return

blah2 :: [a] -> IO (MVar [a])
blah2 = newMVar

class Blah b where
  blah :: [a] -> IO (b a)

instance Blah [] where
  blah = blah1

-- BOOM
instance Blah (MVar []) where
  blah = blah2

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Ok"
```

I get the following error message, which kind of makes sense, but I don't know how to fix it:

```
`[]' is not applied to enough type arguments
Expected kind `*', but `[]' has kind `* -> *'
In the type `MVar []'
In the instance declaration for `Blah (MVar [])'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you want isn't directly expressible.  This is probably as close as you'll get:

```
newtype MVarList a = MVarList (MVar [a])
instance Blah MVarList where
    blah = fmap MVarList . newMVar
```

Comment: I tried playing around with this to get a sense of why an instance of `Blah` where `blah` returns `IO (MVar [a])` isn't possible.  Is it because the "b" type variable in the class definition of `Blah` must refer to a single type?

Comment: It looks like the "b" type variable must be of kind * -> *, and there's no way to write out a type expression from `MyType -> MVar [MyType]`.

Comment: Correct.  For functions there exists `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c` but there is no such composition for rank-1 (or rank-n) types.

Comment: Yeah I came to the same conclusion.  So, Haskell's type system is more expressive than its type syntax!  Weird.

Comment: It's not just syntax — Haskell doesn't support type level lambda expressions at all. Apparently because it makes unification during type inference impossible. See: http://www.mail-archive.com/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/msg20984.html (btw, the UHC/EHC referred to on that page, also **doesn't** support type level lambdas in Haskell syntax)

Comment: You can use the TypeCompose package by Conal Elliot: http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/TypeCompose It would allow you to write `instance Blah (O MVar [])`, where O is the type-level composition.

Comment: @Alexey: That's true, and also roughly equivalent to this: you get a `MVarList` or `MVar :. []` wrapped around your result either way.

Comment: Unification modulo alpha-, beta-, and eta-conversion ("higher-order unification") is semi-decidable and would often be terrifically useful in Haskell type-inference & instance selection.
Backtracking as well.
In some ways, our current theory and mechanisms for instance selection hints teasingly of higher order logic programming (HOLP), including universal & existential quantifiers (as in Lambda Prolog), but falls frustratingly short.
I wonder if we could use full HOLP or something pretty close.
Some tricky issues arise, and I don't know whether they've been vigorously pursued.

Answer (score 2):

I was reading about Conal Elliott's [TypeCompose](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/TypeCompose) library, and was reminded of this question.  Here's an example of how you can do type-level composition.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
module Main where

...

import Control.Compose

...

instance Blah (MVar `O` []) where
  blah = liftM O . blah2

...
```