# Manipulating the order of arguments to type constructors

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

I wrote something like this:

```
instance Functor (Either e) where

   fmap _ (Left a) = Left a

   fmap f (Right b) = Right (f b)
```

How do I do the same if I want `fmap` to change the value only if it's `Left`?

I mean, what syntax do I use to indicate that I use type `Either _ b` instead of `Either a _`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827645  In short, it's not possible in Haskell as it stands now.

Comment: As an aside, the title of this question is somewhat unclear, but I'm not sure what would be better.

Comment: I proposed a more precise title.

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't come up with anything better.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do that directly, unfortunately. With a function you can use `flip` to partially apply the second argument, but that doesn't work with type constructors like `Either`.

The simplest thing is probably wrapping it in a `newtype`:

```
newtype Mirror b a = Mirrored (Either a b)

instance Functor (Mirror e) where
    fmap _ (Mirrored (Right a)) = Mirrored $ Right a
    fmap f (Mirrored (Left b)) = Mirrored $ Left (f b)
```

Wrapping with `newtype` is also the standard way to create multiple instances for a single type, such as `Sum` and `Product` being instances of `Monoid` for numeric types. Otherwise, you can only have one instance per type.

Additionally, depending on what it is you want to do, another option is to ignore `Functor` and define your own type class like this:

```
class Bifunctor f where
    bimap :: (a -> c) -> (b -> d) -> f a b -> f c d

instance Bifunctor Either where
    bimap f _ (Left a)  = Left  $ f a
    bimap _ g (Right b) = Right $ g b

instance Bifunctor (,) where
    bimap f g (a, b) = (f a, g b)
```

Obviously, that class is twice as much fun as a regular `Functor`. Of course, you can't make a `Monad` instance out of that very easily.

Comment: What about `newtype Flip t a b = Flip (t b a)` and then `instance Functor (Flip Either e)`?

Comment: It doesn't work: "All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an) where a1 ... an are type *variables*"

Comment: @m01: It works, but requires enabling a GHC language extension. In practice, I would either (no pun intended) do it the way Norman Ramsey suggests or use the `Bifunctor` class as in my answer. The over-specialized `Mirror` type was meant mostly to illustrate the idea.

Comment: m01: The extension you need is called `FlexibleInstances`.

Answer (score 6):

You can't make the instance you are looking for directly.

In order for type inference and type classes to work, there is a certain positional bias to the ordering of arguments in the types. It has been shown that if we allowed arbitrary reordering of the arguments when instantiating type classes, that type inference becomes intractable.

You could use a [`Bifunctor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/category-extras/0.53.5/doc/html/Control-Functor.html) class that can map over both arguments separately.

```
class Bifunctor f where
    bimap :: (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> f a c -> f b d
    first :: (a -> b) -> f a c -> f b c
    second :: (c -> d) -> f a c -> f a d

    first f = bimap f id
    second = bimap id

instance Bifunctor Either where
    bimap f _ (Left a) = Left (f a)
    bimap _ g (Right b) = Right (g b)

instance Bifunctor (,) where
    bimap f g (a,b) = (f a, g b)
```

Or you could use a [`Flip`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/category-extras/0.53.5/doc/html/Control-Functor-Combinators-Flip.html) combinator like:

```
newtype Flip f a b = Flip { unFlip :: f b a }
```

Generalized versions of both of these are available in category-extras on hackage. The latter even includes an instance for `Functor (Flip Either a)` because `Either` is a `Bifunctor`. (I should probably fix that to only require a [`PFunctor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/category-extras/0.53.5/doc/html/Control-Functor.html#t%3APFunctor))

Ultimately, the order of arguments in a type constructor is important in determining what classes you can instantiate. You may need to use newtype wrappers (like `Flip` above) to put the arguments where they need to be to qualify to construct an instance of another typeclass. This is the price we pay for the inference of type class constraints.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the "it has been shown"?

Answer (score 3):

You essentially need a 'flip' combinator on types. A newtype wrapper that inverts the order should work, as camccann says. Note that you can't use a 'type' synonym, as they may not be partially applied.