# Bind type parameter

Tags: haskell

I am currently working with the quite nice [haskell-eigen](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/eigen) library and stumbled upon a fundamental yet probably basic problem (I am quite new to practical haskell development).

I use their basic matrix type

```
data Matrix a b :: * -> * -> *
```

where a denotes the haskell and b the internal C type. This is realized via the restriction

```
Elem a b
```

with

```
Elem Double CDouble
Elem Float CFloat
-- more for complex types...
```

Although not really the question I want to ask here I kind of don't understand why this is done this way. Since it is obviously a kind of functional mapping I already don't understand why this is formulated as an equivalency relation, but anyway...

I now want to define (as a simple example - I got several) an instance of [Key](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/keys-3.11/docs/Data-Key.html%20Key) from the [keys](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/keys) package. It defines the index key for a given container, for example

```
type instance [] = Int
```

So instances of Key are defined over types of kind * -> *.

However due to that requirement, this won't work:

```
type instance Key Matrix = (Int, Int)
```

I have to in some way make Matrix be of kind * -> *. So (coming from c++ where I would do this using traits classes), I tried this:

```
type family CType a where
    CType Double = CDouble
    CType Float = CFloat

type MatX a = Matrix a (CType a)
```

In other words I tried to use type synonyms as a means of realizing that above mentioned functional type map.

Now I tried the following:

```
type instance Key MatX = (Int, Int)
```

which gives me "The type synonym ‘MatX’ should have 1 argument, but has been given none" and I even tried the obviously wrong

```
type instance Key (MatX a) = (Int, Int)
```

which gives me "Expected kind * -> *, but MatX a has kind *". This sounds to me like "I the compiler expect a type with more than 0 but - being a type synonym - less than 1 argument".

So my question is: How does one commonly map types in haskell in order to solve such a kind mismatch or get rid of it in another way.

P.S.: I am well aware that the eigen matrix has an indexing function, but

1. I want it to be a common one with other data types
2. I have this problem in other variants for other type instances.

**Edit:** Added reference links to mentioned packages.

Comment: I'd get rid of the first half of the question, to be honest. You can reproduce that behaviour with `data Two a b = T` completely. Also, please make sure to include links to the packages. By the way, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335967/manipulating-the-order-of-arguments-to-type-constructors is close to what you're looking for.

Comment: The `Elem` class has a functional dependency, so it expresses a functional relation. Functional dependencies have been around a lot longer than type families, and also offer better APIs in some cases (though I think probably not in this case).

Comment: @dfeuer: That is quite interesting. I kind of assumed that functional maps on types is too fundamental to simply not exist ;). Note also that equivalency relations are simply wrong in these cases. Nothing prevents me from having multiple instances of (Elem Float Anything). Of course the compiler wouldn't allow the ambiguity, but it still seems more reasonable to me to restrict the functional dependency to actual functions (in a mathematical sense). Wouldn't have thought that on type level early haskell was more of a Prolog than a Haskell...

Comment: Who said anything about equivalence relations? The functional dependency means you won't be allowed to have more than one `Elem Float` instance. The second parameter is determined by the first. Today, that's only used for type checking, but I'm hopeful that functional dependencies will ultimately be implemented more like type families, so as to provide proper evidence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're nearly there. The one missing piece is that `type` synonyms must be used *saturated* - that is, you have to supply all of its arguments. `MatX` on its own is not a valid type, only `MatX a`. The reason for this is that `type` synonyms are just synonyms - they're expanded at compile time, which means that the compiler needs to know all of the `type` synonym's arguments in order to get a valid type after expansion.

The fix is to change your `type` synonym to a `newtype`.

```
newtype MatX a = MatX { getMatX :: Matrix a (CType a) }
```

`newtype`s *can* be partially applied, because `MatX a` is now a different type to `Matrix a (CType a)`.

```
type instance Key MatX = (Int, Int)
```

Answer (score 4):

The other answer shows the general case for converting type synonyms into things that can be used in instance declarations. But in this specific case it can be much simpler: since the index type is the same for all different matrices, you can supply just the arguments needed to get the kind correct. Thus:

```
 type instance Key (Matrix a) = (Int, Int)
```

No extra type families relating Haskell and C types needed, no new types needed. This will also make working with the keys' library's API much simpler, as you won't need to do any newtype wrapping and unwrapping around each call.

Comment: I instantly accepted the other answer since I expect to reuse that mapping (MatX) at some other point and it therefore perfectly fit my use case. Your answer however definitely felt more like learning something fundamental and should be the preferred solution in cases where the order of type params is correct. So thanks for sharing.