# Simplfying kind by fixating parameter

Tags: haskell

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981611/bind-type-parameter), but the problem is slightly different in application and reason so I chose to ask a new question.

Consider these definitions (*edit: These are part of an external library*):

```
class (Num a, Cast a b, Cast b a, Storable b, Code b) => Elem a b | a -> b where

data Matrix a b where
    Matrix :: Elem a b => !Int -> !Int -> !(Vector b) -> Matrix a b

instance Elem Float CFloat where
instance Elem Double CDouble where
instance Elem (Complex Float) (CComplex CFloat) where
instance Elem (Complex Double) (CComplex CDouble) where
```

In other words a floating point matrix with underlying C type "fixed" by the functional dependency Elem.

Now in order to implement some instances for certain container specific classes (in my specific case for the [Lookup](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/keys-3.11/docs/Data-Key.html#t:Lookup) class, but Ixed from lens might be another candidate) I need a Matrix type with one type parameter.

I tried the following:

```
type family CType a where
    CType Double = CDouble
    CType Float = CFloat
    CType (Complex Double) = (CComplex CDouble)
    CType (Complex Float) = (CComplex CFloat)

 newtype MatX a = MatX { getMatX :: Matrix a (CType a) }
```

Note that I am not allowed to simply omit the "b" type in the newtype declaration so the type synonym serves as a means to fix the internal type.

However, all functions on the Matrix type have types like

```
(Elem a b) => Matrix a b -> some -> other -> params -> result
```

As an example the unsafeCoeff function looks like this:

```
unsafeCoeff :: Elem a b => Int -> Int -> Matrix a b -> a
unsafeCoeff row col (Matrix rows _ vals) = cast $ Data.Vector.Storable.unsafeIndex vals $ col * rows + row
```

using this type MatX like for example:

```
instance Lookup MatX where
    lookup (i,j) m = Just $ unsafeCoeff i j (getMatX m)
```

gives me the error "No instance for (Elem a (CType a))". Since I am not allowed to specify these instances (since type synonyms are not allowed in instance declarations) I am kind of stuck at this point. I see why the compiler cannot assume that Elem a (CType a) is indeed given, but I don't know how to specify this relation.

Bonus:

I also tried to just do this:

```
instance Lookup (Matrix a) where
    lookup (i,j) m = Just $ unsafeCoeff i j m :: Maybe a
```

But then "b" is the element type of the container and the lookup function must return (the unspecified) b.

Edit: For completeness sake the definition of Lookup from the link above:

```
type family Key f 

class Lookup f where
    lookup :: Key f -> f a -> Maybe a
```

Comment: What is the definition of the class `Lookup`?

Comment: @ReidBarton: I added in the end of the question.

Comment: If a `Matrix` contains an `Elem a b` constraint, then why do the operations on `Matrix` also need a `Elem a b` context?

Comment: That is a very good question. Just to be sure I double checked it and they indeed all have that constraint: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/eigen-2.1.6/docs/Data-Eigen-Matrix.html. Almost all functions are of the kind "cast $ f $ unsafeIndex $ values" where f is the operation and values is a (Storable.Vector b). Maybe cast is typewise underdetermined without the constraint in the function definition. As an example I will add the definition of unsafeCoeff to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to write

```
type instance Key MatX = (Int, Int)
instance Lookup MatX where
    lookup (i,j) (MatX m@(Matrix {})) = Just $ unsafeCoeff i j m
```

Pattern matching on the `Matrix` constructor brings the `Elem a b` constraint it contains into scope. (It's weird that the `eigen` library makes you do this though since it has to match on the `Matrix` constructor anyways.)

---

Edited to add more explanation. The definition of `lookup` above is a shorter way to write

```
lookup (i,j) (MatX m) = case m of
    Matrix _ _ _ -> Just $ unsafeCoeff i j m
```

For pattern matching, see [section 3.17](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-580003.17) of the Haskell Report. The pattern match on `Matrix` looks useless, since it doesn't bind any variables; but it does invisibly bind an `Elem` constraint, which is used in the call to `unsafeCoeff`.

Comment: That does work. Didn't even know I can pattern match on a constructor in an alias (if that is what is happening here). Where does one learn such trickery? All books I have found are just yet another explanation of monads... Works and improves my understanding, so accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't always suggest the right hint, but in this case, when it says `No instance for (Elem a (CType a))`, it really does mean that. You've given it the constraint `Elem a b`, where `b` is determined by the first argument to the function. However, you must be calling something that requires `b ~ CType a`. This is what the compiler can't figure out. You need to restrict the type of your function to `Matrix a (CType a) -> some -> other -> params -> result`, and change the constraint `Elem a b` to `Elem a (CType a)`.

It might be convenient to define synonyms for these:

```
type CMatrix a = Matrix a (CType a)
type CElem = (Elem a (CType a)) -- requires -XConstraintSynonyms
```

An even better alternative might be to remove the functional dependency on `Elem`, if you always intend for `b ~ CType a`. Even if you don't want `b ~ CType a` always, you can still remove the functional dependency and make `CType` an associated type of `Elem`:

```
class (Num a, Cast a (ElemType a), Cast (ElemType a) a, Storable (ElemType a), Code (ElemType a)) => Elem a where
  type ElemType a
  ...
```

Comment: I should have pointed out that Matrix and Elem are part of the haskell-eigen library. I did heavily modify this library in order to factor out some statefulness, but changing these restrictions would amount to a complete rewrite of the library.